# Exibir nome do usuario logado

Tags: php

Boa tarde,
Sou inciante em php e precisaria de um help.

Tenho esse arquivo (index.php) onde quero mostrar o nome do usuário logado na tela apos seu login, porem esta dando um erro de variável indefinida ( $_SESSION).

Observação: desconsiderar a linha do ultimo div=principal

```
            $usuario   = $_SESSION['usuarioSession'];
            $senha     = $_SESSION['senhaSession'];

                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM syslogin WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND senha = '$senha'");

                while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                    $usuario = $linha['usuario'];
                    $senha   = $linha['senha'];
                    }
     ?>
    <div class="bemvindo">Bem Vindo! <strong><?php echo $usuario;?></strong> | Hoje é: <?php echo date('d/m/Y');?></div><!--Bem Vindo-->

    <div id="principal">
                <h3>Bem Vindo(a).</h3><br /><br />
                <img src="css/img/logo1.jpg" alt="logo" />
    </div> <!-- Fim da div#principal -->

    <?php include('includes/fimerodape.php'); ?>
```

Por favor onde estou errando?

Comment: Esse código que você disponibilizou é toda a página? Lembre-se que para trabalhar com SESSION você precisa inicializa-la: session_start(); no começo da página.

Comment: Tenha cuidado que o código que está a usar não o protege contra ataques de *mysql injection*. No minimo passe os inputs pela função [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). E considere alterar para mysqli ou [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 1):

Isso é porque você não iniciou a sessão, faça isso com o `session_start()`:

```
session_start();
$usuario   = $_SESSION['usuarioSession'];
$senha     = $_SESSION['senhaSession'];
```

Recomendo também que faça um `if` para checar se o usuario tem o session.

```
if(isset($usuario)){
    echo "<div class='bemvindo'>Bem Vindo! <strong>$usuario</strong> | Hoje é: ".date('d/m/Y')."</div>";
}
else{
    echo "Você não está logado!";
}
```

Comment: Boa tarde Francisco, Muito obrigado pela dica, mas nao querendo ser chato...poderia me dar mais uma dica em cima desse mesmo problema. Agora esta dando erro em index nao definido ( usuarioSession e senhaSession), o que preciso fazer?  Desde ja obrigado!

Comment: Por isso recomendei o `if`. Ele resolve isso, faz com que não dê erro caso a variavel não esteja setada.

Comment: @GustavoHenrique Se a resposta que eu dei estava certa, por favor marque-a como correta!